# Joomla administrator - VM JQuery Problems

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, virtuemart

Every time I want to save / save & close / close a product in Virtuemart 3, this error appears in my console; and obviously, buttons don't work... what is it? how can I fix it?
http://gyazo.com/b4662b8b36c5f76d3dea95559e08c4df

Comment: I'm not sure why you appear to be having so many issues with VirtueMart. Might be an idea to either consider using a different e-commerce extension or contact the developers of VM

Answer (score 2):

VirtueMart is just recently migrated to Joomla 3. It is not fully comatible with a pure JQuery environment.

Please, check this tip to force Mootools compatibility in legacy code:

**Mootools on Joomla 3.4 - Fix to broken extensions**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/joomla-dev-general/pJ8gi8LypuE/Lsgryh77ClgJ